# Add Events programatically into calender it worked good but now code give Sqlite Exception

Tags: android, calendar

Working at calender adding events programatically it worked good but now code give error all data pass successfully through my method addEvents, but when I Check the calender my event not appear there

this Error Appears:

```
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244): Error inserting calendar_id=2 title=Rfihcd dtstart=1403866800000 dtend=1403869500000 _id=23 organizer=jsmith16420@gmail.com dirty=1 lastDate=1403869500000 eventTimezone=Asia/Karachi into table  Events
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.insertInternal(DatabaseUtils.java:1102)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.insert(DatabaseUtils.java:1227)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarDatabaseHelper.eventsInsert(CalendarDatabaseHelper.java:271)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2.insertInTransaction(CalendarProvider2.java:2174)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at com.android.providers.calendar.SQLiteContentProvider.insert(SQLiteContentProvider.java:96)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:148)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
06-20 16:29:25.137: E/DatabaseUtils(20244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: i am also working on an app using google calendar by any chance you have used "bid" in your code??

Comment: no dear I am not working "bid" in my code